# I synced the settings and extensions on vscode and I want to revert the changes

Tags: linux, macos, visual-studio-code, directory, zsh

So the issue is rather something I caused myself by accident. I was trying to sync two of my computers, a Mac and a Linux. I wanted to sync the Mac to the Linux so I connected my GitHub account to my Mac vs-code when a pop-up displayed that gave two options like "Replace" and "Merge". I wanted to merge the sync but I accidentally hit Replace when all the Settings on my Mac vs-code was replaced.

***What errors do you see?***

And one thing I noticed is that every time I open the terminal it takes me to a path that was defined in my Linux instead of starting at default or $PATH.

***What's the environment and are there recent changes?***

Local, I haven't noticed changes except for the starting path in my VS-code terminal.

***What have you tried to troubleshoot this?***

I did try and I stumbled upon the fact that I can change the terminal's default path in the settings or even in settings.json but I didn't want to cause more problems by overriding any default settings. I also noticed that my Mac vs-code basically just took every setting in my Linux vs-code.
Also, only the terminal in my vs-code was impacted the default terminal on my Mac displayed ~ on login.

And because this was annoying me I basically went on and just added cd ~ to my ~/.zsh_profile so that it just brings me back to ~ but I believe that the Linux settings still have an influence over my Mac vs-code settings and I just want to reverse this. Is there any way I can get back my old configuration? If so how can I do this? Can Github possibly have my old configurations? or is there a reset that I can do that will take me to the very first settings?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you can restore all of your tweaks. You just need to follow these steps:

---

**EDIT**: It seems like VS Code has updated since I made this post and certain things have changed. Try these first:

1. Press `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` (open command palette, shortcuts might be different on your machine).
2. <s>Type `Settings Sync: Focus on Sync Activity (Local) View`.</s>

> **Edit (Aug 2023)**: Type `Settings Sync: Show Synced Data`.

3. You'll notice that the `Primary sidebar` showing three portions of sync related data. The one you need to focus on is called `SYNC ACTIVITY (LOCAL)`.
4. All the changes that you have done to your preferences will show up there, simply click on back arrow icon next to its title to revert the change.

---

Go to **File** > **Preferences** > **Setting Sync is on** (its the last option in the menu).

Then click on **Settings sync: Show Synced Data**. You'll notice *Side Bar* open with 2 sections: **SYNC ACTIVITY** and **SYNCED MACHINES**. Right click on **SYNC ACTIVITY** then tick the **SYNC ACTIVITY(LOCAL)**.

Now you can finally revert the changes that you made before *Accidental Sync* by clicking on the restore icons of each of them.

---

BTW sorry for my broken English, I'm not a native.

Comment: Amazing! Works perfectly.

Comment: When I right click on **SYNC ACTIVITY**, I can't see **SYNC ACTIVITY (LOCAL)**.

Comment: The hint with the Right click on SYNC ACTIVITY did it, preem, there i could select my local settings and restore. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11):

I did something similar and hit "Replace Local" on the machine I wanted to copy over to a new machine. This wiped my extensions and keybindings I've been building up for awhile now and panic ensued.
I found out you can undo syncs at **Settings Sync: Show Synced Data**, but I wasn't seeing my old file contents. For some reason the **Sync Activity (Local)** view is *hidden*. I had to turn it on:

```
... > Views > Sync Activity (Local)
```

Once I did this I could see my old file contents and was able to click the **Restore** arrow button on all of them. Crisis averted!

Comment: You saved me hours of work! Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

I had been using Settings Sync for a while, but my login had expired.  I then logged into the wrong account and got a blank settings.  All the advice above shows as if this is the first time I've used VSCode and there is a single sync history that does not contain my old settings, and now I've signed in to the correct account I worry that when I start VSCode at home it'll nuke everything there too, tho that at least I might be able to recover using the above...